# SQL filter by type on secondary id

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table:

```
id idsec type
1  a     color
2  a     description
3  b     description
4  b     food
5  b     animal
6  c     color
7  d     descritpion
```

I would like to select, all the idsec that don't have the type "color" grouped by idsec.

Comment: Specify the expected result. And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: a list of "idSec"

Comment: Just any values?

Comment: No answer = -1 points? LOL. Anyway i got the right answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `not exists` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.idsec = t.idsec and t1.type = 'color');
```

You can also do aggregation :

```
select idsec
from table t
group by idsec
having sum(case when type = 'color' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below code :-

```
select idsec from table 
where idsec not in (select idsec from table where type = 'color')
group by idsec
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using `minus` set operator

```
with t(id,idse,type) as
(
 select 1,'a','color' from dual union all
 select 2,'a','description' from dual union all
 select 3,'b','description' from dual union all
 select 4,'b','food' from dual union all
 select 5,'b','animal' from dual union all
 select 6,'c','color' from dual union all
 select 7,'d','descritpion' from dual
)
select idse from t group by idse
minus   
select idse from t where type = 'color';

IDSE
----
 b
 d
```

or

```
select distinct idse from t
minus   
select idse from t where type = 'color';

IDSE
----
 b
 d
```

Comment: The `group by` is unnecessary if you are using `minus`.  It gets rid of duplicates by itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need distinct values of `idsec` from the table:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT idsec 
FROM tablename t 
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM tablename WHERE tablename.idsec = t.idsec AND tablename.type = 'color'
  );
```